# Product page attributes are missing in add product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

While adding Products some of the attributes and attribute groups are missing. Below I will add the screenshot of the page. Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: Did you installed any third party extensions? Try disabling them and then check. Also check your error logs for any hints.

Comment: Are your products related to different Attribute Sets? Meaby this is a point?

Comment: No..Its not displaying for anyother Atrribute sets